# Is a redis instance can only work for 1 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm using Rails with redis.

From the introduction of Redis, I found such information:

**start redis server:**

```
redis-server
```

**use redis client:**

```
> redis-cli
redis> set key value
OK
redis> get key
"value"
```

From the sample, I have a question:

Is a redis instance can only work for 1 project? You can see, there is no "database" or "collection" or similar things. If two different projects use the same redis, they may change the same key to invalid value.

So, do I need to create different instances with different ports for different Rails projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sharing a single Redis instance (or cluster) between two or more applications then you should probably namespace your keys to partition them rationally between those applications for the reasons you've observed. Take a look at the [redis-namespace](http://github.com/defunkt/redis-namespace) gem which provides a nice Ruby interface for doing this.

Answer (score 9):

Keep in mind that redis also has databases (16 of them if I remember correctly) – they're just not named, they're numbers. So for example, if you're using `redis-rb` to connect, you'll get a snippet like this:

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379, :db => 5)
```

That'll connect to database 5.  I use this a lot to run tests as well so my tests don't interfere with my development database.

Comment: this is also available in pure redis using the "SELECT" command

Comment: I think it can be more than 16. You can set it in redis.conf by adding "databases 42"  -- http://rediscookbook.org/multiple_databases.html

Comment: According to Salvatore Sanfilippo (creator of redis), there isn't a "maximum" number of databases but rather a recommendation to keep the number small (less than 1000), especially when key expiry is used. Discussion: http://groups.google.com/group/redis-db/browse_thread/thread/ca35385c2919e870